# Haskell - is there extended monad type [ m (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b ]

Tags: haskell, monads

Functor has

```hs
(a -> b) -> m a -> m b
```

Applicative has

```hs
f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Monad has

```hs
m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

But, Is there extended monad type that has

```hs
m a -> m (a -> m b) -> m b
```

or

```hs
m (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
```

?

Comment: `\f x -> join (f <*> x)` has type `Monad m => m (a1 -> m a2) -> m a1 -> m a2`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A `Monad` constraint is sufficient to implement a (sensible) function with that type signature:

```
foo :: Monad m => m (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
foo mf ma = do
   f <- mf
   a <- ma
   f a
```

or, if you prefer:

```
foo' :: Monad m => m (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
foo' mf ma = mf >>= \f -> ma >>= f
```

This means that your proposed operation, even though it *looks* like a generalization of the usual `>>=` bind operation, isn't actually a generalization.  Any `>>=` operation can be written in terms of `foo`, and any `foo` operation can be written in terms of `>>=`, so they are operations of equivalent "power".

In contrast, the other operations are *not* of equivalent power.  Any applicative operation `<*>` can be written in terms of `>>=` and `return`, but you can't in general implement `>>=` in terms of `<*>`, so `>>=` is a strictly more powerful operation, etc.

Comment: It's interesting to note that this captures some notion of taking advantage of the fact that all monads are applicative functors, since you can write (maybe obviously) `foo mf ma = join (mf <*> ma)`.